# MVC ActionLink issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im new to using MVC, so i thought i would give it a try.

I have a problem with my ActionLink:

```
foreach (var item in areaList)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
         @Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, "GetSoftware","Area", new { id = 0 },null);
        </p>
    }
}
```

GetSoftware is my action, Area is my controller.

my error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'AreaID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetSoftware(Int32)
```

my Action:

```
public ActionResult GetSoftware(int AreaID)
{
    return View();
}
```

I checked on here for same questions, and im following the responces but still the same error. Anyone got an idea whats wrong

Comment: Have you tried changing the `new {id = 0}` to `new {AreaId = 0}`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names for the action do not match. Simply use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, "GetSoftware", "Area", new { AreaID = 0 }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, "GetSoftware","Area", new {AreaID = 0 },null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, "GetSoftware","Area", new {AreaID = 0 },null);
```

I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The anonym type that you are sending as a fourth parameter of ActionLink helper must have members with the same name as your action method parameters.

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action","Controller", routeValues: new { id = 0 }, htmlAttributes: null);
```

Action method in controller class:

```
public ActionResult Action(int id)
{
     // Do something. . .

     return View();
}
```

Comment: this is not going to help at all, the "id" parameter is still the same and will still not be found.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the parameter of your action method. As your `ActionLink()` is like the follwoing:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, "GetSoftware", "Area", 
    routeValues: new { id = 0 }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

You should change the controller as the following:

```
public ActionResult GetSoftware(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

This is the default routing behavior. If you you are insisted to use `AreaID` as parameter, you should declare a route in the `RouteConfig.cs` and put it **before** the default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

        // some routes ...

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetSoftware",
            url: "Area/GetSoftware/{AreaID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Area", action = "GetSoftware", AreaID = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        // some other routes ...

        // default route

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach (var item in areaList)
{
  using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     <p>
        @Html.ActionLink(item.AreaName, //Title
                  "GetSoftware",        //ActionName
                    "Area",             // Controller name
                     new { AreaID= 0 }, //Route arguments
                        null           //htmlArguments,  which are none. You need this value
                                       //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
           );
    </p>
  }
}
```